# Mediaplayer Play/Stop issue

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-7.1

I have an mp3 file included in the Resources folder of my Windows Phone 8 project. The file plays in normal scenarios.
However, in case the file is played and stopped many times, it starts giving the following exception when I call **MediaPlayer.Play(song)**:

**Song playback failed. Please verify that the song is not DRM protected. DRM protected songs are not supported for creator games.**

If I try to access **MediaPlayer.State** in such a scenario, it gives me the following error:

**Value does not fall within the expected range.**

Any attempt to play the file after this fails and gives the above error. The file is able to play only after terminating and relaunching the app.

I have also checked the properties of the file and it's protection is Off.

Kindly help me in case any of you have come across the same issue and have a solution for the same.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to create MediaPlayer element dynamically?

```
MediaElement ME = new MediaElement();
ME.Source = new Uri("source of file");
ME.Play();
```